# How to start Xserver at a particular TCP port?

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, virtualization, xserver

I was trying to start a firecracker instance on a different IP and wanted to the export the display to another IP.The recieving IP is not listening at the particular address.So the launch of any GUI application fails with the message(for gedit app).
"(gedit:49): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:39:26.981: cannot open display: 172.27.28.104:0.0
".

Any alternate solutions will also be appreciated.

***This issue occurs in ubuntu 22.04.1 ,possibly due to new gdm3 configurations but we checked it does not occur on ubuntu 20.04.5.***

Comment: So you are running this on Ubuntu Core as this is the only version to just use a 2 digit number.

Comment: No it's actually ubuntu 22.04.1 and the other is ubuntu 20.04.5.

Comment: Please update the question.

Comment: The problem is solved it just required to change "WaylandEnable=false" in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf  as latest ubuntu X11 desktop env is overridden by Wayland

Comment: Maybe you should use the answer your own question option on the bottom of the question and put this in there.

Answer (score 0):

The following change resolves the issue-> Set "WaylandEnable=false" in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf as latest ubuntu X11 desktop env is overridden by Wayland and reboot your system it will be launched with X11 desktop env with xserver running on some default TCP port.